# How to center vertical one symbol in my table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I know that this question in some way is duplicate, but I spent 2 hours trying some solution that I saw on this csite and I failed to solve my problem.

I made next table [image]

and I would like to center vertical and horizontal that `$\varphi$`, and only that (not month in the same row)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{amstext,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}                                      
\usepackage{iwona}                   

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyr}[1]{%      
              {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont#1}%  
                         }                                     

 \begin{document}
 \cyr{ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин}
 \begin{table}[!htbp]                                                                                                                                      
 \centering                                                                                                                  
 \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}                                                                                             
  $\varphi$  & \quad  & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јануар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}       {90}\cyr{Фебруар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Март}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Април}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Мај}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јун}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јул}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Август}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Септембар}$\,\,$\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Октобар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Новембар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Децембар}\end{turn}\\                                     


   \hline                                                                                                                      
   & & & & & & & & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ [-1ex]                                                                   
  $\quad$ & $\quad$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cyr{Трајање грађанског сумрака}}\\                                                 
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\ [-1ex]                                                                                         
    $\circ$   & $\quad$  & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m \\                                                                                                                                                                                 
    40   & $\quad$  & 30 & 28 & 27 & 28 & 31 & 33 & 32 & 29 & 27 & 27 & 29 & 31 \\                                            
    42   & $\quad$  & 31 & 29 & 28 & 29 & 32 & 34 & 33 & 30 & 28 & 28 & 30 & 32 \\                                            
    44   & $\quad$  & 32 & 30 & 29 & 30 & 34 & 36 & 35 & 31 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 33 \\                                            
    46   & $\quad$  & 34 & 31 & 30 & 31 & 35 & 39 & 37 & 33 & 30 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\                                            
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\[-1ex]                                                                                        
  $\quad$ & $\quad$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cyr{Трајање астрономског сумрака}}\\                                               
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\[-1ex]                                                                                        
    40   & $\quad$  & 96 & 96 & 90 & 97 & 111 & 123 & 117 & 102 & 92 & 90 & 94 & 98 \\                                        
    42   & $\quad$  & 99 & 94 & 93 & 101 & 117 & 132 & 125 & 106 & 95 & 93 & 97 & 101\\                                      
    44   & $\quad$  & 102 & 97 & 97 & 105 & 125 & 145 & 134 & 112 & 99 & 96 & 100 & 105         \\                                    
    46   & $\quad$  & 106 & 100 & 100 & 110 & 134 & 162 & 147 & 118 & 103 & 99 & 104 & 109 \\                                 
\hline                                                                                                                      
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                 
\end{table}     
\cyr{ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: If your document is in Serbian, there's no point in using `\cyr`: `\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}` should be sufficient.

Comment: @egreg It is not only on Serbian.

Comment: In any case, `\cyr` is not the solution

Comment: @egreg Honestly, I have problem when I am using sebianc babel. That is the reason why I use `\cyr`, and that command I saw in some your answer (and all works fine for me). For example, I can compile your code in solution, but there is warning message http://i.imgur.com/mNMvXQE.png

Comment: You need to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg I don't think that is problem. I will try to fix it using this tutorial http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=newlang. If I had problem I will ask in new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it needn't be an exact centering, maybe the following  small modificitation will be enough (the precise value in `\raisebox` to be chosen}?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{amstext,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}                                      
\usepackage{iwona}                   

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cyr}[1]{%      
              {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont#1}%  
                         }                                     

 \begin{document}
 \cyr{ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин}
 \begin{table}[!htbp]                                                                                                                                      
 \centering                                                                                                                  
 \begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}                                                                                             
%  $\varphi$  & \quad  & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јануар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}       {90}\cyr{Фебруар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Март}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Април}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Мај}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јун}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јул}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Август}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Септембар}$\,\,$\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Октобар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Новембар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Децембар}\end{turn}\\                                     
\raisebox{20pt}{$\varphi$ }
& \quad  & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јануар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}       {90}\cyr{Фебруар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Март}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Април}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Мај}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јун}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Јул}\end{turn} &  \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Август}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Септембар}$\,\,$\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Октобар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Новембар}\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}\cyr{Децембар}\end{turn}\\              

   \hline                                                                                                                      
   & & & & & & & & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ [-1ex]                                                                   
  $\quad$ & $\quad$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cyr{Трајање грађанског сумрака}}\\                                                 
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\ [-1ex]                                                                                         
    $\circ$   & $\quad$  & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m \\                                                                                                                                                                                 
    40   & $\quad$  & 30 & 28 & 27 & 28 & 31 & 33 & 32 & 29 & 27 & 27 & 29 & 31 \\                                            
    42   & $\quad$  & 31 & 29 & 28 & 29 & 32 & 34 & 33 & 30 & 28 & 28 & 30 & 32 \\                                            
    44   & $\quad$  & 32 & 30 & 29 & 30 & 34 & 36 & 35 & 31 & 29 & 29 & 31 & 33 \\                                            
    46   & $\quad$  & 34 & 31 & 30 & 31 & 35 & 39 & 37 & 33 & 30 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\                                            
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\[-1ex]                                                                                        
  $\quad$ & $\quad$ & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\cyr{Трајање астрономског сумрака}}\\                                               
   & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\[-1ex]                                                                                        
    40   & $\quad$  & 96 & 96 & 90 & 97 & 111 & 123 & 117 & 102 & 92 & 90 & 94 & 98 \\                                        
    42   & $\quad$  & 99 & 94 & 93 & 101 & 117 & 132 & 125 & 106 & 95 & 93 & 97 & 101\\                                      
    44   & $\quad$  & 102 & 97 & 97 & 105 & 125 & 145 & 134 & 112 & 99 & 96 & 100 & 105         \\                                    
    46   & $\quad$  & 106 & 100 & 100 & 110 & 134 & 162 & 147 & 118 & 103 & 99 & 104 & 109 \\                                 
\hline                                                                                                                      
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                 
\end{table}     
\cyr{ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your input can be vastly simplified and the phi exactly centered.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}
\usepackage{amstext,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,booktabs,calc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{iwona}

\newcommand{\turnhead}[1]{\begin{turn}{90}#1\end{turn}}

\begin{document}
ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
\toprule
\settowidth{\dimen0}{Септембар}% measure the widest month
\raisebox{.5\dimen0-.5\totalheight}{$\varphi$} & 
  \turnhead{Јануар}    & \turnhead{Фебруар} & 
  \turnhead{Март}      & \turnhead{Април}   &
  \turnhead{Мај}       & \turnhead{Јун}     &
  \turnhead{Јул}       & \turnhead{Август}  &
  \turnhead{Септембар} & \turnhead{Октобар} &
  \turnhead{Новембар}  & \turnhead{Децембар}\\
\midrule
        & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Трајање грађанског сумрака} \\
$\circ$ & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m & m \\
40      &  30 &  28 &  27 &  28 &  31 &  33 &  32 &  29 &  27 & 27 &  29 &  31 \\
42      &  31 &  29 &  28 &  29 &  32 &  34 &  33 &  30 &  28 & 28 &  30 &  32 \\
44      &  32 &  30 &  29 &  30 &  34 &  36 &  35 &  31 &  29 & 29 &  31 &  33 \\
46      &  34 &  31 &  30 &  31 &  35 &  39 &  37 &  33 &  30 & 30 &  32 &  35 \\
\addlinespace
        & \multicolumn{12}{c}{Трајање астрономског сумрака}\\
\addlinespace
40      &  96 &  96 &  90 &  97 & 111 & 123 & 117 & 102 &  92 & 90 &  94 &  98 \\
42      &  99 &  94 &  93 & 101 & 117 & 132 & 125 & 106 &  95 & 93 &  97 & 101 \\
44      & 102 &  97 &  97 & 105 & 125 & 145 & 134 & 112 &  99 & 96 & 100 & 105 \\
46      & 106 & 100 & 100 & 110 & 134 & 162 & 147 & 118 & 103 & 99 & 104 & 109 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
ТЕКСТ сдаоп чфиондф фгпоин инафонг ачоигнаои ачоингачфоин
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `.5\dimen0-.5\totalheight` What measure `\totalheight` in this example? And I used here `[utf8x]`, because there was warning message about that. And `\newcommand` is pretty nice, because everything look simpler now. And `\addlinespace` is nice command (instead of adding new row, like me).

Comment: @Cortizol `\totalheight` measures the whole height and depth of the phi (height is what's above the baseline, depth is what's below it).

Comment: Ah, that is for phi. Ok, I get it now. Thanks.